# reusable javascript function not taking the variable

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to learn javascript and write a reusable function. I followed a tutorial and of course you can pass either a variable, or the exact data type- and I am trying to change the color of `<div id="age">`. The changeColor function worked, when displayE1 was called explicitly inside the function. I want to be able to change the color of anything, and passing displayE1, 'age', and 'displayE1' didn't work.

```
   <div id="age"></div>
    <button onclick="changeColor('blue', displayE1);" >blue</button>
    <button onclick="changeColor('red', age)">red</button>



    <script type="application/javascript">
        var age = "age"
        function grabAge() {
            var result = prompt('how old?', '');
            var displayE1 = document.getElementById("age");
            displayE1.innerHTML = result

            function changeColor(newColor, idReference) {
                idReference.style.color = newColor;
            }
        }
        grabAge()
    </script>
```

This worked

```
function changeColor(newColor) {
    displayE1.style.color = newColor;
}
```

Why isn't this function reusable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not reusable because the function is NOT defined in window scope as you are calling it. It is a local method to the `grabAge` method. Also `displayE1` is also not in global scope.

For your code to work, it would need to look line this

```
var age = "age", displayE1;
function grabAge() {
    var result = prompt('how old?', '');
    displayE1 = document.getElementById("age");
    displayE1.innerHTML = result
}

function changeColor(newColor, idReference) {
    idReference.style.color = newColor;
}

grabAge();
```

Notice how `changeColor` is not inside the other method and `displayE1` is defined outside the function.

Comment: what would put it in the window scope? what is window scope?

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be

```
function changeColor(newColor, ele) {//You need to the second argument
    var element = document.getElementById(ele);
    element.style.color = newColor;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="changeColor('blue', 'displayE1');" >blue</button>
<button onclick="changeColor('red', 'age')">red</button>
```

Provided, both the second arguments are IDs

Comment: I use idReference for the second arg, and I call displayE1 in the button click that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You create variable displayE1 into a function.
It is your error because variables created in function is not global! 
If you want to use that variables, you need create it in global namespace.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var age = "age";
    var displayE1 = document.getElementById("age");

    function grabAge() {
        var result = prompt('how old?', '');
        displayE1.innerHTML = result

        function changeColor(newColor, idReference) {
            idReference.style.color = newColor;
        }
    }
    grabAge()
</script>
```

Comment: I do not show the working code.
I just showed where there should be a variable displayE1 in this code!